# How do I get the default value of a generic type?

Tags: d

I'm using the D language, and would like to get the default value of a generic type, similar to the way `default(T)` works in C#. Is this possible? If not - what are the possible workarounds?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think `T.init` might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 12):

Every type in D has a default value. It's accessed via the type's `init` property. `int.init`, `float.init`, `Object.init`, etc. In the case of a templated type, it's still the `init` property. For example, if you had the generic type `T`, it would be `T.init`.

`init` is generally the closest to an error value that the type has. For integral types, it's `0`. For `bool`, it's `false`. For floating point types, it's `NaN`. For character types, it's `\u00FF`. For references (i.e. classes) and pointers, it's `null`. And in the case of structs, it's whatever the value that its member variables are directly initialized to are. e.g. In the case of

```
struct S
{
    int a = 17;
    bool b;
}
```

`S.init` would be an instance of `S` whose `a` was `17` and `b` was `false`. Of particular note, the need for the `init` property is the reason that structs in D cannot have default constructors. Their default state - that is, their `init` property - must be known at compile time, whereas a constructor would be run at runtime, so the default value of a struct can't be created with a constructor, and so, while structs can have constructors, they can't have default constructors.

In the case of enums, the `init` property depends on the sort of enum that it is. A manifest constant such as

```
enum i = 7;
```

would have the same `init` property as its type (`int` in this case), since you didn't really create a new type. However, for enums which actually create a new type, e.g.

enum E { a = 7, b = 17 };

the default value is the first value in the enum. In this case, `E.init` would be `a`.

Arrays are where it gets a bit interesting though. The `init` property for dynamic arrays and associative arrays is `null`. However, when you allocate memory for an array (be it static or dynamic), each element is initialized to its type's `init` property. So, with arrays, you have both the matter of their `init` value and the `init` value of their elements.

In any case, the generic way to get the default value of a type is `T.init` where `T` is the type that you want the default value of - be it a specific type or a template parameter.

Comment: Worth noting that `char.init == '\xFF'`.

Comment: I figured that I'd miss some types, but I couldn't think of what when I wrote my initial answer. Hopefully, they're all in their now.

Comment: @JonathanMDavis: Is it true that If I declare local variable in main() function lets say int i; without initializing it it's default value will always be 0?

Comment: @PravasiMeet Variables are default-initialized to their `init` value, and `int.init` is `0`, so yes.

Answer (score 1):

Re enum, according to [codepad.org](http://codepad.org/):

```
enum Foo {
  a = 3,
  b = 2,
}

import std.stdio;
void main() { writef("%d", Foo.init); }
```

gives:

> 3

Comment: Of note, however, is the fact that `writeln(Foo.init)` would print `a` rather than `3`.